# ASP.Net HttpModule / ErrorHandler - how to get executing assembly version

Tags: .net, asp.net, error-handling, httpmodule, nlog

I have a Http module that handles all of the errors for my ASP.Net application.

As part of this it hands of to the "MyApp.Logging" assembly which is a facade to NLog.

In here I want to get the version number of the **web** applciation that caused the error in the first place.

I have tried this code which works fine in a console application...

```
version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Any ideas how to get this working in the context of a web application?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
typeof(SomeTypeFromYourWebApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Comment: With it being called via a HttpModule the idea is that this can be placed into any website. So there might not be a common type. Of course the module could pass in the version number using your approach above - I'll investigate it.

Comment: To any web site or to a lot of them at once? For the first case I can suggest to have configuration section that states what type to load using reflection.